# How to pass select tag selected property to component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-hooks, foreach

How to pass select tag selected property to component state via useState maybe. First the option values are coming from react props. I'm passing props from app.js file from the array Authors=[{...},{...}]. So I need to render the options values later.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-rmfn5j?file=/src/components/NewTask.js:42-129

```js
const NewTask = ({ authors }) => {
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState();
  return (

<select value={author}>          // passing the author to useState
  {authors.map((author) => (
    <option key={author.author_name} value={author.author_name}>
      {author.author_name}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
)
```

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean. create an onchange handler on the select tag and in that setAuthor? `onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}`

Comment: select has no `value` attribute. you need to add `selected` attribute to your option

Comment: @Sysix not necessarily in React context you do [can pass `value` prop](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/select#controlling-a-select-box-with-a-state-variable).

Comment: oh sorry, today I learned something again :)